# ASP.NET CORE 2.1 cross-thread impersonation

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, powershell, asp.net-core

I have a really weird issue in ASP.NET core 2.1
I am writing a simple web application, which at needed scenario calls Powershell scripts. 
Impersonation works perfectly on C# level, but as soon as I invoke Powershell script, it is being invoked with default identity (the one that IIS Express is running with).
I know that in ASP.NET it was easy to enable cross-thread impersonation via aspnet.config file, but I have no clue how to perform similar implementation in ASP.NET Core.
Below code is function in question (though function is not a problem I guess).

```
    internal void InvokeScript()
    {
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();

        Impersonation.LogonUser(userName, domain, password, 2, 0, out 
        SafeAccessTokenHandle handle);

        WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(handle, () => {

            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
            ps.Runspace = runspace;

            //Setting needed variables

            Collection<PSObject> PreFixOutput = new Collection<PSObject>();
            Collection<PSObject> FixOutput = new Collection<PSObject>();
            Collection<PSObject> PostFixOutput = new Collection<PSObject>();

            // Setting directory to needed KB subdir and finding needed stage files

            string KBtoWorkWith = RepositoryLocation + @"\" + KB.Number;

            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(KBtoWorkWith);

            // Reading scripts from .ps1 and adding needed variables

            string commandToRun1 = string.Format("$Computer = '{0}'; $Username = '{1}'; $KB = '{2}' ; {3}", IP, Username, KB.Number, File.ReadAllText("Pre" + KB.Number + ".ps1"));
            string commandToRun2 = string.Format("$Computer = '{0}'; $Username = '{1}'; $KB = '{2}'; {3}; {4}; $success; $verbose", IP, Username, KB.Number, File.ReadAllText(KB.Number + ".ps1"), InnerFunction);
            string commandToRun3 = string.Format("$Computer = '{0}'; $Username = '{1}'; $KB = '{2}' ; {3}", IP, Username, KB.Number, File.ReadAllText("Post" + KB.Number + ".ps1"));

            // Invoking formed PS scripts & collecting returned data

            ps.AddScript(commandToRun1);

            PreFixOutput = ps.Invoke();

            OutputToUser = PreFixOutput[1].BaseObject.ToString();

            if (PreFixOutput[0].BaseObject.ToString() == "True")
            {
                IsFixApplicable = true;

                if ((PreFixOutput[2].BaseObject.ToString()) != "")
                {
                    InnerFunction = PreFixOutput[2].BaseObject.ToString();
                }

                else
                {
                    InnerFunction = "";
                }

                FixOutput = ps.AddScript(commandToRun2).Invoke();

                OutputToUser = FixOutput[1].BaseObject.ToString();

                if (FixOutput[0].BaseObject.ToString() == "True")
                {
                    PostFixOutput = ps.AddScript(commandToRun3).Invoke();

                    OutputToUser = PostFixOutput[1].BaseObject.ToString();

                    if (PostFixOutput[0].BaseObject.ToString() == "True")
                    {
                        WasFixApplied = true;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        WasFixApplied = false;
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    WasFixApplied = false;
                }
            }

            else
            {
                IsFixApplicable = false;
                WasFixApplied = false;
            }

            //runspace.Close();
        });

    }
```

Comment: What happens if you move `Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();` **inside** the impersonation?

Comment: Sadly, then I get Access Denied while opening needed registry error, while opening runspace, which was mentioned to be really common with system.management.automation library.

Answer (score 0):

Just for everyone to know. I have never solved this in DEV environment. Neithet on ASP.NET CORE, nor on ASP.NET 4.5.2 . This looks to be an IIS Express issue. As soon as I have hosted fully functional IIS on my machine and published my app impersonation started working.